# Embedded Code works in ASP UpdatePanel but not in Telerik RadAjaxPanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, telerik, updatepanel

The following `If` statement works correctly if it was in `ASP:UpdatePanel`, However, if we used a `Telerik:RadAjaxPanel` instead, the code will be totally ignored  so the result of the following code will be two controls:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel2" runat="server" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" EnableAJAX="true" >

    <% If 1=1 Then%>
    <uc1:DefaultSidebar1 runat="server" ID="DefaultSidebar1" />
    <%
    Else%>
    <uc1:DefaultSidebar3 runat="server" ID="DefaultSidebar3" />
    <%
    End If%>
</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
```

What is the reason behind that? Any Suggestions to get it work in a `RadAjaxPanel`.

Comment: Could you not make the usercontrols visible=false and then in the codebehind determin which should be visible or not.

Comment: so how you resolved this?

Answer (score 0):

Please consider moving that logic in the `Page_Load` `!Page.IsPostBack` codebehind, using

```
if(1=1){
    DefaultSidebar1.Visible = true;
} else {
    DefaultSidebar3.Visible = false;
}
```

This is the best option if you need to ajaxify the controls.